# Evaluating src in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to define the src in eval() but not working !! the eval line is not working. This is google console taking the error. The hyperlink is not working.
[image] [image: TypeError]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        var num = 1
        img1 = new Image()
        img1.src= "images/slide1.jpg"
        img2 = new Image()
        img2.src= "images/slide2.jpg"
        img3 = new Image()
        img3.src= "images/slide3.jpg"

        function slideShow(){
            num = num + 1
            if(num == 4){
                num = 1
            }
        document.slide.src = eval("img" + num + ".src")//having problem in this line
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="javascript:slideShow();">Click here for next image</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you use `eval` there? Better to remove it entirely, it serves no purpose

Comment: what can i use instead ?

Comment: Nothing at all, you're already concatenating, you don't need an `eval` call on top of it

Comment: Removing it, console reads: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Comment: Indeed, see the linked question

Comment: I haven't learned jquery yet and this single line is hampering the whole code. I will see what I can get from the linked answer.

Comment: There's no need at all for jQuery, don't worry

Comment: the problem was actually in the image tag... there should be another attribute:  name="slide"... Solved

Comment: You should be using standard DOM methods to access elements, rather than relying on `document` properties. Use `document.querySelector` to select an element instead

Comment: Yes, that's a better option to choose